# Html data showing � (questions marks) instead of characters

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, character-encoding

[image]

From the above image im getting **?** symbols in option in database there is a chareter present how can i resolve this issue..

I have a header like this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

And i am looking for permanent solution this is my code:

and when print the variable it is coming like this:`console.log(getContact);`

[image]

```
    function get_question_detail(q_id){
    $("#all_option").html("");
    var temp_ques = sessionStorage.getItem(q_id);
    if (temp_ques){
    var getContact = JSON.parse(temp_ques);

    for (var j = 1; j <= ans_option_count; j++) {
    var temp_var = "sr_no" + j;
    var full_div = '<div class="answer_option"><input type="radio" name="ans_option" value="' + j + '"  class="validate[required]"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + getContact['option'][temp_var] + '';
    $("#all_option").append(full_div);
    // console.log(full_div);
    }
```

Comment: i think this content is copy paste content, remove the actual content shown in  "?" then retype it.

Comment: 1-Use one header (UTF-8 is best). 2-Be sure that your file is saving UTF-8 without bom. 3-If these questions coming from mysql then be sure you executed "SET NAMES utf8" sql command.

Comment: @kodmanyagha can you tell me how can i set in sql.  `$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }`

Comment: After connection execute this command. If you use mysqli you can call that: mysqli_query("set names utf8");

Comment: @kodmanyagha i have tried this way but not working: `if ($conn){ mysqli_query("set names utf8"); }`